# Gradle project sync failed after finish setting up dependencies for Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-authentication

By following assistant of Firebase (AndroidStudio: Tool> Firebase), I tried to add Firebase AUthentication to my app.
But after setting up the dependencies, Gradle project sync failed with error as belows.
I am struggling to fix this issue...anyone can help me?

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency
>   depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0. 1]", but isn't
>   being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will
>   be unknown. Dependency failing:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 ->
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
>   15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1. The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have
>   transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@17.1.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@16.0.5
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth@4.1.0 For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.

## Buid.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
}
```

## Biud.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.poc.android.myhospitals"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think this line has the problem

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:**16.0.1:15.0.0**'

it should be like this

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:**16.0.1**'

**suggestion :**

- update all of your libraries to the latest versions
- add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
- exclude support module from every firebase library

  ```
  implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6') {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much!! After I updated all libraries to the latest versions and implement "firebase-core", it works.

Comment: I wanted to upvote, but it seems i need at least 15 reputations for voting...I am so sorry. After i get the reputation, i will definitely upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Please update your library with below version code**

implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2")

- update all of your firebase libraries to the latest versions